# Android code to set wallpaper to phone screen size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I make use of the following code to set my static images as wallpaper from my android app.. The image dimensions are like 425*700, 280*180, 600*400 etc., so the image dimensions are not the same.

```
            try {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(context);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int fullWidth = size.x;
            int fullHeight = size.y;

            // int fullWidth = wManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
            // int fullHeight = wManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();

            Log.d("Debug", Integer.toString(fullWidth));
            Log.d("Debug", Integer.toString(fullHeight));

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.drawable.hello));

            Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, fullWidth,
                    fullHeight, true);
            myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(
                    bitmapResized.getWidth(), bitmapResized.getHeight());

            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmapResized);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But the images are quite streched and doesn't look good after setting as a wallpaper in the phone.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem lies in the resources as you have already mentioned. For a good view/quality of wallpaper we have to use different resources of images as according to the resolution of your device, if you want to use your application of setting the wallpaper to be used by many devices without making any changes(an apk). The  crux is, you need a better quality image matching the resolution of your device. Hope it helps.

Edit: The distortion is again  because you are resizing your image for covering full screen size. I guess if you do not resize it, it might work, though I havent use it till now.